# Favicon not showing up when running my React project

Tags: reactjs, favicon

Favicon not showing up when running my React project. However, when I click **index.html**, the icon appears. When I call **npm start**, when localhost opens I see my pages without icons. I tried every way and even though I made many changes, I could not reach the result. I will be glad if you help.

The file structure of my project is as follows.
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkiw4.png)

and index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Trying Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using create-react-app to start the project?

Comment: Problem solved. Thx.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68886133/9715289

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clear the cache in your browser, this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Just add version parameter for the favicon path to force your browser to refresh the pic

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

Then you can delete it, the icon will remain.

Answer (score 2):

**Your icons should be in public folder.** For importing correctly you have to start all your paths with "%PUBLIC_URL%/myIcon.ico" and this "%PUBLIC_URL%" will be resolved into public folder (where your index.html is placed by default).

**(inside index.html on public folder)**
**exemple:** `<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.png" />`

Comment: Yes this solved the issue for me, images should be in the public folder!